# How to keep a window on top of a running game?

Tags: vb.net, fullscreen, always-on-top

I'm writing a program and I want it **to be displayed even on top of a game running in full-screen mode** *(like counter-strike)*.

I'm using Visual Basic as programming language. Every single help is appreciated.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Thanks for answering @roryap ! I have searched Google (of course) and other forums. But..unfortunately I cant find anyting so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543765/bring-vb-net-window-on-top-of-all-windows

Comment: Yeah, I had already checked that. But I pretty much didnt understand it!

Comment: @jhegeman2 It won't work. As he said, he want the program **to be displayed even on top of a game running in full-screen mode** ! And these game aren't at topmost. It's "a special state"...

Comment: what i do in those "special cases"?

Answer (score 0):

[Display window over full screen application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228325/display-window-over-full-screen-application/51335334#51335334)

But this is not the best option. In full screen mode there is exclusive access to the display, and you can only display on top of this if you are allowed to implement it if it's a game in OpenGL, DirectX and BackBuffer to impose your data.

Comment: Please don't just post links - include the essential portion of the linked information in your answer itself.

Answer (score -1):

It's not so complicated. You just have to read [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543765/bring-vb-net-window-on-top-of-all-windows/8544152#8544152).

> The simplest way of making a window top-most is to specify the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` flag when you create the window. The .NET Framework hides most of the window creation work behind the scenes, but you can customize the parameters when you need to by overriding the [`CreateParams property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.createparams.aspx) of your form class.

Here's the code :

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
    Get
        Const WS_EX_TOPMOST As Integer = &H00000008

        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TOPMOST
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

**But anyway, because this won't work. It's not a good solution as I said to *jhegeman2*.**

Comment: I ll wait for your response!

Comment: I think there's no solution... As _Rudedog2_ said [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1560ec2-1503-4ed7-ac9e-ea61b18805cc/show-form-over-full-screen-game-window?forum=vbgeneral) :
`"Unless you run your games in a window mode, you're going to have issues. Most games completely take over the display and popping up windows is not really an option without it giving windows back the display.  You may have luck drawing your own, but it would compete with the game for display on the screen."`

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243748/vb-application-on-top-of-a-game/9244289#9244289)'s another good answer.
There's also a possible alternative : creating a DirectX overlay like what Steam does. There's a couple questions around doing this : [stackoverflow.com/questions/3549004/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549004/fullscreen-directx-overlay-yes-again-c-sharp) [stackoverflow.com/questions/2649702/…](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649702/c-sharp-hook-overlay-a-directx-game).

Comment: The previous links are written in C# but it doesn't matter, it'll give you an idea and it'll aways be possible to convert the code to vb.net... ;)

Comment: In all the forums I've found, the answer is : "You can't". [There's another good example of thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?457910-Application-on-top-of-a-(fullscreen)-DirectX-program) proving that it's not possible. I think you can give it up :/ Sorry for you.

Comment: `WS_EX_TOPMOST` won't work for a DirectX _full-screen_ game.  You'll just end up _taking_ the game out of full-screen when your window appears

Comment: Yes, it's what I said.